# XSL Sort only on one node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using the following XSLT,but the order of nodes after sorting is a bit problem for me as they are not following the same order as of the input.

```
enter code here
```

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Types">
            <xsl:sort select="Type1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SecondTypes">
            <xsl:sort select="Type1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ServiceOption">
            <xsl:sort select="Issue"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ServiceConcession">
            <xsl:sort select="Concession" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>                                
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Types|self::SecondTypes|self::ServiceOption|self::ServiceConcession)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get just the **<Type1>** text or do you want the **<Types>** node containing **Type1** nodes?

Comment: Hi, i would like to sort the <Type1> node within <Types> node only.Not the <Type1> node in <SecondTypes>.

Comment: Good question +1. See my answer for knowing the immediate approach to sorting operations.

Comment: @user:you have expanded your question with new requirements. Are you still searching for an answer?

Comment: Hi empo, I have found the solution by modifying the existing XSLT. But now the issue is the order of these nodes after sorting ... If <Types> nodes are before <SecondTypes> nodes as input,then in output their order is reversed, Its the same case with other nodes as well though they are sorted. After sorting does the order gets changed ? Can we make sure the nodes are coming in the same position as of the input xml.

Comment: Please add also the input XML. The question is now much more complex and using a single template could not be the proper way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the identity transformation so that sort is applied to the wanted nodes only:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Types">
                <xsl:sort select="Type1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Types)]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 - had me stumped. Spent a good 10 min on this without success. Nice Work!

Comment: @Brandon you are welcome. This technique is really easy and fast to apply. I'm not an expert, but I don't see any counterindication.

Comment: @user843436: Do note that this stylesheet will also move `<Types>` elements after the `<SecondType>` elements, or to be more precise, `<Types>` elements will be the last child elements of the `<book>` element.

Comment: @jasso, if order matters, you can _obviously_ change the order of the `apply-templates`. In this situation is enough. In other situations this unwanted effect might be difficult to fix I imagine and it would probably be easily to leave the identity transformation as is and add a second template.

Comment: @jasso fixed to reflect the original sequence of the input tree.

Comment: @empo: The real reason I mentioned that effect is that the given input is already in a way a special case. The `<Types>` elements have other siblings before (author) **and** after (SecondTypes) so simply changing the order of the `<apply-templates>` doesn't remove the issue, it only changes the way how the issue appears. Generally I agree with you, if the order matters, it would probably be easier to use also another template. (If the `<Types>` elements had other elements in between them, the nature of the whole question would be different. I'm not talking about such convoluted cases.)

Comment: @jasso, yes did not care about `author` element :)), just post a quick answer. Also OP does not care. Thanks for your comments, they are a clear insight and source of the possible _counterindications_.